# How to implement ObservableCollection<InterfaceType> from abstract class in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a abstract base class that implements properties from an interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractItem : IPropertyListOwner
{
    public ObservableCollection<IProperty> Properties { get; }
}
```

My concrete class now also needs to implement concrete properties:

```
public class ConcreteItem : AbstractItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<ConcreteProperty> Properties { get; }
}
```

How do I achieve that? Right now I see the following approaches:

> 1. Simply use a separate property, don't use that from base class

```
public class ConcreteItem : AbstractItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<ConcreteProperty> ConcreteProperties { get; }
}
```

> 1. Return a new filtered ObservableCollection

```
public class ConcreteItem : AbstractItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<ConcreteProperty> ConcreteProperties
    {
        get { return new ObservableCollection<ConcreteProperty>(base.Properties.OfType<ConcreteProperty>()); }
    }
}
```

What would you do? Any better approaches?

Comment: If your concrete class inherits from an abstract class that already contains the properties, why do you need to override it again in the concrete class?

Comment: I have multiple concrete classes that might use different implementations of IProperty. Sorry for not beeing clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics will help you:

```
interface IPropertyListOwner<T>
  where T : IProperty
{
    ObservableCollection<T> Properties { get; }
}

abstract class AbstractItem<T> : IPropertyListOwner<T>
  where T : IProperty
{
    public abstract ObservableCollection<T> Properties { get; }
}

class ConcreteProperty : IProperty { }

class ConcreteItem : AbstractItem<ConcreteProperty>
{
    public override ObservableCollection<ConcreteProperty> Properties 
    { 
        get
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

But this will be inconvenient, if you're planning to work somewhere with `IPropertyListOwner`.

Suppose, you have some code, that should work only with `IProperty`. For example, let this code display names of properties:

```
interface IProperty
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

In the case of generics, you can't write `foreach`, that will iterate through collection of properties, without knowing `T` at runtime:

```
void WritePropertyNames<T>(IPropertyListOwner<T> owner)
{
    foreach (var property in owner.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
    }
}
```

In other words, to do something with generic `IPropertyListOwner<T>` you will need code with generics too.

If you'll post use cases, than it will help to post more clear answer.

Comment: Simple question from coding practices, Is it OK to use generics in interfaces?

Comment: Of course it's OK. Why this shouldn't be OK? :) FCL contains many generic interfaces.

Comment: Do you need an `AbstractItem` Class here since I see it is being overriden by the `ConcreteItem`? More over there is no `virtual` or `overriding` defined. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bharath: you're right about virtual/overriding, it's a typo. About `AbstractItem` - may be OP has any additional payload in his real code.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for the sample. I can learn a lot here! Right know I need to learn the C# Generics basics - I've missed something :)
Indeed I need to work with IPropertyListOwner. E.g. I have a simple PropertyHelperUtil that gets and sets the properties from an IPropertyListOwner

Comment: @Dennis Could you clarify what you mean with "this will be inconvenient" when working with IPropertyListOwner?

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class AbstractItem<T> : IPropertyListOwner where T:IProperty
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> Properties { get; private set; }
}

public class ConcreteItem : AbstractItem<ConcreteProperty>
{

}
```